# About the json problem returned by the PHP parsing api

Tags: php, json, curl

First of all, sorry for my poor English, I use a company's text review api (to filter the user name that does not comply with local laws and regulations), through him, I can get the scores of some items to distinguish whether he is in violation, The return content of the server is a json. I want to get the corresponding score by reading the serial number of "lable" for the following use, but there are multiple "lable", and if there is one item, it will not be In a certain order, so I can hardly think of a solution. **(Main question: How to get the corresponding score through "lable")**, thank you for your patience

```
<?php
function curl_post_https($url,$data) {
// Simulate submit data function
$curl = curl_init();
// Start a CURL session
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// address to access
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// Check the source of the certificate
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
// Check if the SSL encryption algorithm exists from the certificate
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
// Simulate the browser used by the user
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
// use automatic jump
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
// Automatically set the Referer
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Send a regular Post request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
// Post submitted packet
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
// Set the timeout limit to prevent infinite loops
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// Display the contents of the returned Header area
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// The information obtained is returned as a file stream
$tmpInfo = curl_exec($curl);
// perform the operation
    if(curl_errno($curl)) {
        Echo 'Errno'.curl_error($curl);
     // catch the exception
    }
curl_close($curl);
//Close the CURL session
    return $tmpInfo;
    //return data, json format
}
$result_json = curl_post_https('https://aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/antispam/v2/spam',array('access_token' => '24.de91542f26612322bf152af17e24620c.2592000.1540919681.282335-14329580','content' = => '操你妈'));
$result = json_decode($result_json, true);
$log_id = $result["log_id"];
$spam = $result["result"]["spam"];
$review = $result["result"]["review"];
$reject = $result["result"]["reject"][0]["hit"];
$reject_echo = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($reject); $i++) {
    $reject_echo = $reject_echo.$reject[$i].' | ';
}
echo 'Server returns json:<br>'.$result_json.'<br>'.' Unique identifier: '.$log_id.'<br>'.'Text review result: '.$spam.'<br> ';
echo 'prohibited word list: '.$reject_echo.'<br>';
$pass_info = $result["result"]["pass"];
$pass_info_echo = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($pass_info); $i++) {
    $pass_info_echo = $pass_info_echo. 'Prohibited detection score: "'.$pass_info[$i]["score"].'" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Prohibited type: "'.$pass_info[ $i]["label"].'" <br>';
}
$reject_info = $result["result"]["reject"];
$reject_info_echo = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($reject_info); $i++) {
    $reject_info_echo = $reject_info_echo. 'Prohibited detection score: "'.$reject_info[$i]["score"].'" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Prohibited type: "'.$reject_info[ $i]["label"].'" <br>';
}
$review_info = $result["result"]["review"];
$review_info_echo = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($review_info); $i++) {
    $review_info_echo = $review_info_echo. 'Prohibited detection score: "'.$review_info[$i]["score"].'" &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Prohibited type: "'.$review_info[ $i]["label"].'" <br>';
}
$baokongweijing_score = $pass_info[0]["score"];
$wenbenseqing_score = $pass_info[1]["score"];
$zhengziminggan_score = $pass_info[2]["score"];
$eyituiguang_score = $pass_info[3]["score"];
$dizhuruma_score = $pass_info[4]["score"];
$diziguansui_score = $pass_info[5]["score"];
the items passed by echo ' are as follows: <br>'.$pass_info_echo;
the items that echo 'does not pass are as follows:<br>'.$reject_info_echo;
echo 'The items that need to be reviewed are as follows:<br>'.$review_info_echo;
echo 'The scores of each item are as follows: <br>'.'Terrorism is prohibited: '.$baokongweijing_score.'<br>'.'Text porn: '.$wenbenseqing_score.'<br>'.' politically sensitive: '. $zhengziminggan_score.'<br>'.' Malicious promotion: '.$eyituiguang_score.'<br>'.'Low insult: '.$dizhuruma_score.'<br>'.'Low quality irrigation: '.$diziguansui_score;//Display its corresponding score

?>
```

**The error should be at:**

```
$baokongweijing_score = $pass_info[0]["score"];
$wenbenseqing_score = $pass_info[1]["score"];
$zhengziminggan_score = $pass_info[2]["score"];
$eyituiguang_score = $pass_info[3]["score"];
$dizhuruma_score = $pass_info[4]["score"];
$diziguansui_score = $pass_info[5]["score"];//Write the score to the function
```

Because he only checked the pass (pass), but did not detect the option to reject/review, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: _"The error should be at"_ - What error? You need to show us the actual content of `$pass_info` and explain what you're actually trying to do. What result are you currently getting? The question is currently super unclear. Remember, we have _no idea_ what you're trying to do or what the response looks like. We are 100% depending on you to explain it to us properly.

Comment: Usage of $pass_info: The project passed from json (//Get the project passed from json)...

Comment: Analysis results:
The scores for each item are as follows:
Panic banned: 0.0099999997764826
Text porn: 0.7379999756813
Politically sensitive: 0
Malicious promotion: 0.27147358208955
Low vulgarity: 0.014000000432134
Low quality irrigation:

Comment: As you can see, item 5 did not pass, so it was not shown in the score because he only got the score passed.

Comment: Sorry for my rashness

Comment: Please update your question to include _all_ relevant info, like a `var_dump($pass_info)` _and_ what the expected result should be. Without that, we won't have a chance of knowing what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the JSON back from the API, you can create a couple of arrays which use the `label` fields as the index to the arrays.  This uses [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the data.

To ensure that all elements have a value, it first creates a blank array (using `array_fill()`) - you will need to ensure that the `0,5` creates all of the elements you need (so all possible values of `label`). Then it adds in the values from the JSON using `array_replace()`...

```
$result_json = curl_post_https('https://aip.baidubce.com/rest/2.0/antispam/v2/spam',array('access_token' => '24.de91542f26612322bf152af17e24620c.2592000.1540919681.282335-14329580','content' => '操你妈'));
$result = json_decode($result_json, true);
$rejects = array_fill(0,5,["score" => 0]);
$pass = array_fill(0,5,["score" => 0]);
$rejects = array_replace($rejects, array_column($result['result']['reject'], null, "label"));
$pass = array_replace($pass, array_column($result['result']['pass'], null, "label"));

print_r($rejects);
print_r($pass);
```

Which in this case outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [score] => 1
            [hit] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 操你妈
                    [1] => 操你
                )

            [label] => 5
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0.0099999997764826
            [hit] => Array
                (
                )

            [label] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0.7379999756813
            [hit] => Array
                (
                )

            [label] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0
            [hit] => Array
                (
                )

            [label] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0.27147358208955
            [hit] => Array
                (
                )

            [label] => 4
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [score] => 0.014000000432134
            [hit] => Array
                (
                )

            [label] => 6
        )

)
```

(As you can see the 0,5 isn't enough as the last entry is 6)